# Electronic sensor of some kind but what?

Tags: sensor, identification

I purchased a house and I found two sensors which I have no idea what they are for.  It is simply a tube that fits into another tube.  The inner tube has batteries and you can slide it out.  Anyone know what this sensor is what is it for?  Thanks in advance to solve his puzzle.

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]

After digging it out, it appears that it is indeed a mole wacker.

[image]

Comment: Is that a sprinker where you found this?

Comment: In the backyard.  I have two of them.  When I pulled it out, the inner tube inside was wet.

Comment: That's a piezo transducer alright. If it isn't used for scaring moles, it may be used for ranging, perhaps to detect water level. (Put a fishing weight on a string down that hole; if some length of the string comes up wet, you have a low tech replacement.)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'm leaning more towards water level monitor.  I'm going to take a shovel and dig around it to see where it ends.  If I don't report back, something bad happened :) BTW..How would piezo transducer detect water?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be a [sonic mole repeller](https://www.google.com/search?q=sonic%20mole%20repeller&tbm=isch).  It looks like a cap is missing from one end.  That end (shown in the third picture) has what looks like a piezoelectric transducer that is used to make sound to repel the moles.  Perhaps they mounted it in the pipe to make it easier to change the batteries.

[image]

(From http://www.victorpest.com/sweeneys-solar-power-sonic-spike-s9014 )

Comment: Upvoted for being plausible.  I will look at it in details in the morning.  Thank you!

Comment: So in the end, you never had rats?